# How To Trigger Implicit Composition Animations

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Following the only documentation I could [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/implicitanimations), I tried the following XAML:

```
<Image Name="testImage" Source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" Width="800">
    <animations:Implicit.Animations>
        <animations:ScalarAnimation Target="Translation.Y" ImplicitTarget="Offset" Duration="0:0:4"/>
        <animations:ScalerAnimation Target="Opacity" Duration="0:0:4" />
    </animations:Implicit.Animations>
</Image>
```

The following code works and the opacity animates and takes 4 seconds to fade:

```
private void myButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    testImage.Opacity = 0.2;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to trigger a translate animation (or rotate or scale).  I've tried this:

```
private void myButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var translate = new TranslateTransform();
    translate.Y = 400;
    testImage.RenderTransform = translate;
}
```

And also this hoping the implicit would override the duration but no luck:

```
private void myButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    testImage.Offset(0, 400, 0).Start();
}
```

The changes are applied in these, but no 4 second animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TranslateTransform` is a `RenderTransform` and is not related to the `Composition` transform you want to achieve and the `Offset` implicit animation overrides the XAML setting.

To make it work, you need to get hold of the `ElementVisual` and then change the `Offset` directly:

```
private void myButton_Tapped( object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e )
{
    var imageVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual( testImage );
    imageVisual.Offset = new Vector3( 0, 400, 0 );
}
```

Comment: In case anyone follows this Q & A the answer is correct but the XAML in my example needs to change from ScalarAnimation to Vector3Animation.  Also this [document](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/08/26/interop-between-xaml-and-the-visual-layer/#FmE5F5VfwPADx0GM.97) helped me understand the Composition API much better.